# Custom accessory in uitableview doesn't call accessorybuttontapped delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a custom cell that I create like this:

```
CategoryCellTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"poiCell"];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[CategoryCellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"poiCell"];
}

// Get current POI
Rank * poi = [_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.text.text = poi.name;
cell.categoryImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animals.png"];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map"]];
cell.accessoryView = imageView;

return cell;
```

The accessoryView shows up. But when I click on it, it doesn't come in my:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Accessory clicked");
}
```

Do I need to set some delegate right? I thought this was already implemented for you so you could always use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your own handler for you custom view. This delegate method called only for default accessory button.

For example you may add custom UIButton with image as accessory view and add target and action to this button.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to make sure there is no beter way. Still junior in iOS development.